# Axios get method wont display any results

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to grab user data from json file. I am using axios get method. It doesn't display anything on my page. It's just blank. Could anyone assist me?

```
.users(v-for="user in users")
    p {{ user.name }}
```

```
data ()  {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUsers() {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.users = data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
  },
```

Comment: can you please share more code ? Do you ever call your method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `fetchUsers` method. Call it in `created` section.

```
created() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about this. Can this also be used under `mounted: function () {}` ?

Comment: definitely you can